# Dell PowerEdge R900 adding Storage

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, storage

I have a Dell [PowerEdge R900](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/pe_R900_spec_sheet.pdf) ([manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r900_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf)) ([getting started guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r900_setup-guide2_en-us.pdf)) with 5 each 3.5 inch SATA drives which add up to around 8TB.

I want to mount or add an external USB or any other way connect another backup drive of 10TB so that i can backup all my 8TB drives to this 10TB.

What would be the best way to connect this HDD to the Server? I think USB 3.0 would be very slow.

Please let me know if you require more information about ports etc i would be happy to attach pictures of inside out.

Comment: USB 3.1 (aka USB 3.1/gen 2) is convinent and fast.

Comment: But according to https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r900_setup-guide2_en-us.pdf he only has USB 2.0 in that server.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" requires a value judgement which is out of bounds here, but you may get more traction over at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ especially since according to your [Getting Started Guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r900_setup-guide2_en-us.pdf) you don't have anything faster than USB 2.0 or Gigabit Ethernet, and therefore will need to add an interface card for any of these options below except #5.

We *can* address the issue of speed:

1. Add a Thunderbolt 3 drive box (40 Gbps) and a "Thunderbolt 3" "PCIe card" (web search for it that way), unless your motherboard already supports it, like [some Gigabyte gaming boards](https://www.gigabyte.com/mb/thunderbolt3/overview), in which case, all you need is the cable and box.
2. USB 3.1 (10 Gbps)
3. eSATA (6 Gbps)
4. USB 3.0 (5 Gbps)
5. Gigabit Ethernet (1 Gbps) to another PC